# Trying to make a set of class objects go in a circle in Pixi JS

Tags: javascript, math, pixi.js

I want my snake to go around in a circle when [A] or [D] are pressed and go straight when they aren't.

For some reason what happens instead is that I press the keys and it switches between going up, right, both, and then neither.

Here's my relevant code, it's the part of my gameLoop function that determines the snake's movement
`

```
window.addEventListener('keypress', e => {
        console.log(e);
        if(e.code === "KeyD" )
        {
          angle -=1;
          if(angle >360 )
          {
            angle = angle%360;
          }
          /*if(angle <0 )
          {
            angle == 360;
          }*/
          console.log("Angle: " + angle);
          
        }
        if(e.code === "KeyA")
        {
          angle +=1;
          if(angle >360 )
          {
            angle = angle%360;
          }
          /*if(angle <0 )
          {
            angle == 360;
          }*/
          console.log("Angle: " + angle);
         
        }
      })
      
      //initialize speed multiplyer var
      //let v = 5;
      let v= .1;
      for (let i = 0; i < segments.length; i++) 
        {
        segments[i].y += v*  Math.floor(Math.cos(angle),16); //today I learned that Javascript can't do trigonometry correctly due to rounding errors
        console.log("X:"+segments[i].x + "Angle: " + angle);
        segments[i].x -= v*   Math.floor(Math.sin(angle),16);
        console.log("Y:"+segments[i].y + "Angle: " + angle);
        
        }
```

`

Comment: please prepare working example in jsfiddle, codesandbox, https://www.pixiplayground.com or similar. Then it will be easier to help

Comment: @domis86 [Here](https://people.rit.edu/~smh8786/235/project3/)'s the actually page up and running

Comment: Yeah i see now in https://people.rit.edu/~smh8786/235/project3/App.js - you have put `window.addEventListener('keypress', e => {` inside `gameLoop()` function. But `gameLoop()` function is executed on every frame of ticker (`app.ticker.add(gameLoop);`). This means that on every frame you are adding new listener to `keypress` event :) Please move   `addEventListener` outside `gameLoop()`.

Comment: also, why you commented out `if(angle <0 )`  ?

Comment: I fixed that by making it like this `window.onkeydown`, but now I'm still getting the same problem

Comment: still `window.onkeydown = (e)=>{` is inside function `gameLoop()` . I already said: "Please move addEventListener outside gameLoop()" - so also please move `window.onkeydown` outside.